# git tag -v error: could not create temporary file: Operation not permitted

Tags: git, repo

When I execute "repo init -u ssh:XXX@XXXX -b release", it shows

***error: could not create temporary file: Operation not permitted***

According to my judgment, verity the Repo gpg error.
then enter  "/android/.repo/repo/.git" directory ,execute "git tag -v v1.12.16",it shows

***liu@ubuntu:~/test/LINUX/android/.repo/repo/.git$ git tag -v v1.12.16***

***error: could not create temporary file: Operation not permitted***

Now stop here,because I don't know how to work about "git tag -v XXX". Does it need to create temporary file? if so, where it will create.

thx.

Comment: Recently,by  analyzing git source code .I found "git tag -v XXX" will make a temp file in "/tmp"，version v1.7.9.5 use "mktemp” and v2.21 use "open".Then they all have the same error "Operation not permitted".

Answer (score 0):

Today, I use "creat" instead of "open" on V2.21.0（wrapper.c-int git_mkstemps_mode(char *pattern, int suffix_len, int mode),,mode is 0600）. Then  it's OK.

```
507         for (count = 0; count < TMP_MAX; ++count) {
508                 uint64_t v = value;
509                 /* Fill in the random bits. */
510                 filename_template[0] = letters[v % num_letters]; v /= num_letters;
511                 filename_template[1] = letters[v % num_letters]; v /= num_letters;
512                 filename_template[2] = letters[v % num_letters]; v /= num_letters;
513                 filename_template[3] = letters[v % num_letters]; v /= num_letters;
514                 filename_template[4] = letters[v % num_letters]; v /= num_letters;
515                 filename_template[5] = letters[v % num_letters]; v /= num_letters;
516 
517         //      fd = open(pattern, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, mode);
518                 fd = creat(pattern, mode);
519                 if (fd >= 0)
520                         return fd;
521                 /*
522                  * Fatal error (EPERM, ENOSPC etc).
523                  * It doesn't make sense to loop.
524                  */
525                 if (errno != EEXIST)
526                         break;
527                 /*
528                  * This is a random value.  It is only necessary that
529                  * the next TMP_MAX values generated by adding 7777 to
530                  * VALUE are different with (module 2^32).
531                  */
532                 value += 7777;
533         }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, the parameter `--quiet` may help.

`repo init -u ssh:XXX@XXXX -b release --quiet` would not comfirm the gpg keys.